# Unable to debug web api call from angular JS - IIS (when other then default app pool) - visual studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, debugging, iis, asp.net-web-api, application-pool

When I run web api and angular web applications using `Default application pool` then i able to debug the web api service.
If change application pool for both the applications to custom app pool as below.
then, debug point is not called in web api.

IIS 8

web api applicaiton: app pool name: apppool1 - integrated - 4.0, (4.5.2 framework)

asp.net web (only angular and html files): app pool name: apppool1 - integrated - 4.0

can any one please help, what is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue by re-installing IIS. it able to attach debugger now.